# The entity or complex type 'Ws.Models.XXXX' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am working along with my MVC4 WEBAPI project. All i am doing is generating a web service using a DTO(samplemodelDTO) which is as follows.

```
namespace Ws.Models
{
    public class samplemodelDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { set; get; }

        public string Productname { get; set; }

        public int Productquantity { get; set; }

        public string ProductReview { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

This DTO is used in the controller as follows, as it is fetching data from the two tables. I have searched a lot, also used anonymous object but it's still throwing the same inner exception.
Also i searched here, but i am still unable to find any solution. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.Cheers.

```
public IQueryable<samplemodelDTO> Getproducts()
{
    var query = from t in db.products
                join p in db.ratings on t.product_id equals p.prod_id
                select new samplemodelDTO()
                {
                    Productname = t.product_name,
                    Productquantity = t.quantity,
                    ProductReview = p.rating1
                };

    return query;
}
```

The error which it is throwing is this[image]

Comment: Is it required that you return an `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: Either you're not showing the full `samplemodelDTO` class declaration or your EF context is somehow aware of the `samplemodelDTO` type and considers it to be part of the EDM. Does one of your Entities refer to `samplemodelDTO`? If the answer is yes, you need to realize that DTOs are not meant to be part of the domain models and are only used to transfer data in a type-safe way.

Comment: I tried both ways , List and IQueryable as well. But didnt get anything out of it

Comment: @haim770 its the full DTO class bro .

Comment: @haim770 , my context is not aware of DTO. And i know that its meant for data presentation for the client side as it provides flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below one, Use namespace different from context model's for a safer side.

```
namespace <NewNamespaceforDTO> //Ws.Models 
{
    public class samplemodelDTO
    {            
        public int id { set; get; }    
        public string Productname { get; set; }  
        public int Productquantity { get; set; }   
        public string ProductReview { get; set; }    
    }
}

public List<samplemodelDTO> Getproducts()
{
     var query = from t in db.products.AsEnumerable()
                 join p in db.ratings.AsEnumerable() on t.product_id equals p.prod_id
                 select new samplemodelDTO()
                 {
                      Productname=t.product_name,
                      Productquantity=t.quantity,
                      ProductReview=p.rating1
                 };
      return query.ToList();
}
```

It might be useful.

Comment: This will also retrieve both tables completely into memory, and perform the join in-memory. Performance will not benefit from this solution.

Comment: Why to use a different namespace other than in which my models and context reside? i didnt get that  @Razak Raz

Comment: @Razack Raz, Thanks for the tip. Can you please tell me whats AsEnumerable is doing here ? Why it wont work without the AsEnumerable ?